# Check data inside database and change value depending on retrieved data

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

In my database I have a number of users. The database stores a value (an URL of an image) for each user whether he's red a message or not. All users are displayed beneath the message, so they can press their name when they've red it. What I want is that when an user clicks on his image, the code has to change the URL of the image depending of it's value. More like a switch. For example:
If the value say "on" I need the code to change it to "off". 
If the value is "off" I need the code to change it to "on".

In my case, on is "read.png" and off is "unread.png".
All the values are sent over the addressbar, I use `$_GET` to get the value.

The code I have:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
$url = $_POST['url'];           // read.png
$herstel = $_POST['herstel'];       // unread.png
$tabel = $_POST['tabel'];           // urlJef
$tabel_content = $result2[$tabel];          // content from $tabel
if ($tabel_content == $url){
    $sql = "UPDATE " . mysql_real_escape_string($tbl_name) .
       " SET ".$_GET['tabel']." = '".$_GET['herstel'].
       "' WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
} 
else if ($tabel_content == $herstel) {
    $sql = "UPDATE " . mysql_real_escape_string($tbl_name) .
       " SET ".$_GET['tabel']." = '".$_GET['url'].
       "' WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

**EDIT**

```
if($result){
    echo "top.location.href = 'index.php';"; 
}else {
    echo "That didn't work";
}
```

Both code's are working separatly. So if I create just an `if-statement` it works. Both code's. But somehow if I mix the two of them (by adding the "else if-statement"), only one of the two works.

What am I missing?

Comment: This statment is not right (`$tabel_content = $result2[$tabel];`). You should use `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);` then `$tabel_content = $row[$tabel];`

Comment: thanks rullof for the time helping me, that solved the problem! It works both ways now! Many many thanks! At least I can go to bed before midnight now...

Comment: Ok Since it worked i restored the answer with edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

You can't send data using `"POST"` and `"GET"` methods at the same time. It must be only one of them, but in your code your using `$_POST` and `$_GET` to retreive that data. You have to check which method you're using to send your data the use the appropriate array, or you can use `$_REQUEST` which works with both of them.

Since your sending the data using `GET` method your code should be like this: ( every `_POST` is changed to `_GET`).

Also you can't get content from $tabel this way (`$tabel_content = $result2[$tabel];`). You should use `$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);` then `$tabel_content = $row[$tabel];`

```
$sql2 = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
$result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
$url = $_GET['url'];           // read.png
$herstel = $_GET['herstel'];       // unread.png
$tabel = $_GET['tabel'];           // urlJef
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
$tabel_content = $row[$tabel];
if ($tabel_content == $url){
    $sql = "UPDATE " . mysql_real_escape_string($tbl_name) .
       " SET ".$_GET['tabel']." = '".$_GET['herstel'].
       "' WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
} 
else if ($tabel_content == $herstel) {
    $sql = "UPDATE " . mysql_real_escape_string($tbl_name) .
       " SET ".$_GET['tabel']." = '".$_GET['url'].
       "' WHERE id = ".$_GET['id'];
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: I changed everything like you said, doesn't seem to work. I tried to change it all to _POST and _REQUEST, both gives an error. The _GET does work on the users that doesn't have the "herstel" value yet. So they can mark their faces to "read.png", but this can't be set to "unread" since this value isn't sent with the link. If I add this value in the link, I get an error.

Comment: the link: <a href="markRead.php?id=<? echo $rows_mw['id']; ?>&url=read.png&herstel=unread.png&tabel=urlJef">

Comment: not actually an error. I have    if($result){
 echo "worked!"; 
}else {
    echo "Didn't work";      So it just displays the error on the screen, nothing else.

Comment: I also tried both else if and elseif but this doesnt seem to make a difference

Comment: Could you include a screenshot

Comment: I completed the code on top of the page, right under the EDIT. The full code is in the main question now. Hope this is clear enough?

Comment: Please add the html part and if possible upload a screenshot of your browser were the error generated

Comment: entertainyou.nl/helpShot01.jpg and entertainyou.nl/helpShot02.jpg holds the screenshots (it's in Dutch, I changed the code above partly in English, the screenshots are the originals, there are some Dutch parts in it, i.e. the result in the second screenshot is written in Dutch. It is exactly the same error code as displayed in the html on screenshot 01

Comment: Add echo '('.$tabel_content.')'; after $tabel_content = $result2[$tabel]; to check if it's empty